# How to simulate M/M/1 using omnet++?

Tags: queue, omnet++, inet

I am new in using omnet+ + , I am trying use INET framework to simulate queueing model M/M/1  on server-side  based on FIFO discipline

Firstly, I found INET support external output queue such as FIFO a DopeTailqueue, I try to edit it and to make it work on input data not output, but I am not sure if I am in the right way.

My question, how can I simulate the M/M/1 queue in which layer and how can I calculate the arrival rate and processing rate?​

Comment: Wouldn’t you be specifying arrival rate and processing rate if you’re setting up a simulation? These are parameters, not outputs.

Comment: how can I specify the arrival rate and processing rate? is that mean I have to set a value for them at the start of simulation?

Comment: @ama- generally, these are determined based on data collected on the real-world system that is under study. Or, if the system is in the design phase, these would be part of a set of calculations done as part of a line balancing activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your task has nothing to do with actual protocols (just a generic queuing question), you would be better off with the queuing tutorial in the base OMNeT++ installation (omnetpp/samples/queuenet). You can quite easily assemble various queueing models.

Comment: thanks Rudi for your answer... can I have your email address?

Comment: I already find code that does the M/M/1 but as a  separate simple module, but I want to add that to the  standHost (INET), where I should add that ( between Mac layer and network layer .??)

Comment: I am trying to implement M/D/1 queue model on link using oment and inet framework. ? how can I do that? there is no layer on the link module? I implemented M/M/1 queue on the mac layer interface on stader host but in the link, there is no layer so where I can add queueing model ??